# i keep getting error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written "import sqlContext.implicits._"; However it still does not work. It is right in spark-shell. Why it is not right in this situation? I have see many other methods to translate rdd to data frame, but most of my code has been written as toDF(). How to do to make toDF work? the error:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import sys.process._

"rm -f ./ml-1m.zip".!
"wget http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-1m.zip".!

"ls ./ml-1m.zip".!

"rm -r ./ml-1m".!
"unzip ml-1m.zip".!

"ls ./ml-1m".!

val ratings_raw = sc.textFile("./ml-1m/ratings.dat")
ratings_raw.takeSample(false,10, seed=0).foreach(println)

case class Rating(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Float)
val ratings = ratings_raw.map(x => x.split("::")).map(r => Rating(r(0).toInt, r(1).toInt, r(2).toFloat)).toDF().na.drop()
```

Comment: Which version of **Spark** are you using?

Comment: Spark version = 2.3.0

Comment: If you look at the [**Documentation** of `SqlContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) you will see, that since `2.0.0` this class is _"deprecated"_. You should use an [`SparkSession`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) instead, and import the implicits like this `import spark.implicits._`

Comment: can you please send me the exact way to import SparkSession becaus i used this solution and still does not work  
 `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession  
//val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)  
import spark.implicits._  `
the error is :error: stable identifier required, but this.$line7$read.spark.implicits found.
       import spark.implicits._
                    ^

Comment: You need to instantiate the `SparkSession` first, and assign the value to **val** called **spark** _(by convention)_. In the _shell_ you don't need to do that, since _(as Joohnnie already said)_ the shell already provides you with such instance. If you are writing an App then you need to instantiate it using the `builder` as it is show in the [**Documentation**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession), you may as well read the [basic introduction to Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/quick-start.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are in spark-shell, you don't need to create new SQLContext

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

you can use spark directly

```
scala> import spark.implicits._

scala> val ratings_raw = sc.textFile("./ml-1m/ratings.dat")
ratings_raw: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ./ml-1m/ratings.dat MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:38

scala> case class Rating(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Float)
defined class Rating

scala> val ratings = ratings_raw.map(x => x.split("::")).map(r => Rating(r(0).toInt, r(1).toInt, r(2).toFloat)).toDF().na.drop()
ratings: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [userId: int, movieId: int ... 1 more field]

scala> ratings
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [userId: int, movieId: int ... 1 more field]

scala> ratings.printSchema
root
 |-- userId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- movieId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- rating: float (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, it works fine!

However, I used spark session as below

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
            .master("local")
            .appName("test1")
            .getOrCreate()
```

Instead of deprecated

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: @MehdiSelbi , I used Spark version 2.4.0